# C# recovery techniques from a timeout

Tags: c#, sql, exception, command, recovery

If I have a "Timeout Expired" exception, what can be a good ways to recover from it and continue doing what you are doing by trying again calling the same routing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        /////put your code here
        break; // Exit the loop. Could return from the method, depending
               // on what it does...
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log, I suspect...
    }
}
```